# Golang - ParseForm ; err = mime: expected slash after first token

Tags: forms, go

Am getting this `Error = mime: expected slash after first token`
 Some details below.

The goal is a login form that the username and password 
can be extracted from the POST.

I also tested a curl post and a static html form --> same issue = `mime: expected slash after first token`

Snippet of the  go code:

```
log.Printf("\n\n\t[loginH()] - POST method ...\n")
err := r.ParseForm()
if err != nil {
        // Handle error here via logging and then return
        DebugLog.Printf("[loginH()] - ERROR: with r.ParseForm. (err=%v)\n", err)
        log.Printf("[loginH()] - ERROR: with r.ParseForm. (err=%v)\n", err)
}
username := r.Form["username"]
passwd := r.Form["passwd"]
log.Printf("[loginH()] - r.Form ... username=%s and passwd=%s\n",username,passwd)
```

The html/form is:

```
<form method="POST" action="/login">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Email Address"/>
    <input type="password" name="passwd" placeholder="Password"/>
    <input type="submit"  id="loginBtn" name="login" value="Logon"/>
</form>
```

Output is:

```
2016/12/15 21:36:07 [loginH()] - POST method ...
2016/12/15 21:36:07 [loginH()] - ERROR: with r.ParseForm. (err=mime: expected slash after first token)
2016/12/15 21:36:07 [loginH()] - r.Form ... username= and passwd=
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers/information/enlightenment.

r.Form is empty

Comment: small update -- using

Comment: @Motakjuq -- Thanks for clean up on the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error comes from line 85 of [mediatype.go](https://golang.org/src/mime/mediatype.go).  You're probably getting this error from a call to ParseMediaType method internally. From there it seems like your static form or curl is not setting some value of Content-Type or Content-Disposition correctly. Please check these headers for any problematic values.

From docs:

```
// ParseMediaType parses a media type value and any optional
// parameters, per RFC 1521.  Media types are the values in
// Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers (RFC 2183).
// On success, ParseMediaType returns the media type converted
// to lowercase and trimmed of white space and a non-nil map.
// The returned map, params, maps from the lowercase
// attribute to the attribute value with its case preserved.
```

Comment: Thanks!  I dug into the source mediatype.go, to find that string.

Your note helped isolate the issue, there was a proxy that was modifying the Content-Type Header.   I moved the server and was able to confirm that the form post was working.  

 I appreciate your time.